# Custom query with JPA DataTables (jquery Datatables)

Tags: java, datatables, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a web page where I get a jquery DataTable with a list of rows connected to the id of a field I'm passing through the form.
I'd like to create a DataTable that uses a sort of "native query" using a parameter inside the method of my controller.
Something like:

```
   @Query("Select * from ... where ...=:id ", native="true")
   public DataTablesOutput <Object> findByField (@Param(value="id")id, input);
```

I know it doesn't work, but I haven't understood at all how Specification and QueryDSL work with the DataTable repository, so could someone please make a simple example with objects instead of generics?

(The id I'm passing is a column of the resultSet from the Database, but it's not mapped in the object I get on java, because I'm trying to make the query lighter and nonrecursive)

Comment: pls someone help meee